# Why am I getting a red interlaced screen when I increase monitor resolution?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, visual-artifacts

I have an Nvidia GTS 240, with which I have been running dual monitors at 1920x1080 each up until now.

I have upgraded one of the monitors, and it is capable of 2560x1440, which appears in the control panel. However if I select the increased resolution on this monitor I get a very red screen with what looks like every second line having the underlying image (every other line is red).

According to the Nvidia specs, the graphics card can support up to 2560x1600.

I'm pretty sure I have dual-link cables. I have upgraded the Dell monitor drivers and the Nvidia drivers.

What is causing this, and what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the monitor cable fixed this problem.
The pins on the new cable are exactly the same as the old one, not sure if that means there's something wrong with the old cable, or if there's more to it.

Comment: If the whole screen is too red, too yellow, or tinted just about any color, the most common cause is a misadjusted or damaged monitor. It can also be caused by problems with the monitor **cable**, the video card connector, or the monitor connector. For more information take a look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/680689/what-causes-this-graphical-glitch-in-my-web-browser/680699#680699), especially the link at the bottom of the answer. Also your question would be improved if you edited it by adding the "visual-artifacts" tag to it