# Intense graphical glitching

Tags: windows-10, firefox, memory, nvidia-graphics-card, visual-artifacts

Twice now, I've walked away from my computer for long enough that the screen turns off and then come back to this:

[image: Picture of the problem]

This time, it was only a firefox window, but the last time, the problem extended to my desktop.

My specs are listed [here](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/Legion/Lenovo_Legion_Y545?M=81Q6000GUK), according to the OEM. As it is a laptop, I'm concerned it might be RAM degredation, as listed in [this](https://superuser.com/q/680689/968848) question.

My current theories are as follows:

- Something regarding Windows update. I'm using the june 9th 1903 release (cmd says that's Version 10.0.18362.900)
- Perhaps it's a driver issue. I can try updating my graphics driver.
- Perhaps Firefox is having issues with hardware acceleration. I can try disabling that.
- RAM artifacts? This would be pretty serious, as the computer is only 6 months old and ram replacements are difficult on laptops.

Comment: If it is only 6 months old it should be under warranty. So replace it.

Comment: I've been looking into warranty coverage, but I'd rather not be out of a computer for up to ten weeks if it's just a software issue.